# how do you store variables in dash core components

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am trying to store a variable into memory using dash_core_components.Store, but it doesn't seem to be saving the incremented number to memory. what I want to happen is everytime I press the button, the number stored in memory increases by 10 - instead the variable doesn't seem to be saving and just outputs 15.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

x = 5

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Store(id='memory-data', data = {'the-data': x}),
    html.Div([
        html.Button('click me', id='add-button')
    ]),
    html.Div(id='debug-out'),
])

@app.callback(dash.dependencies.Output('debug-out', 'children'),
             [dash.dependencies.Input('add-button', 'n_clicks')],
             [dash.dependencies.State('memory-data', 'data')])
def button_pressed(clicks, data):
    
    data['the-data'] += 10
    return data['the-data']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't outputting to the `dcc.Store` component, so it never changes.  That's why it keeps returning 15. What you would have to do is set up two callbacks, like in [this example from the docs](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/store). One updates the data in the store, and the other retrieves the updated data.